# dynamic creating is not working on shared server

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I do not understand what is the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/shaliapin777/x8R9R/1/

here everything is ok!
but in `shared server` doing nothing.

this is my code:

```
<?php
    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url,'/');
    $url = explode('/',$url);
    if(empty($url[0])){
        header('location: http://lingo.ge/dictionary/eng-ka');
        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://lingo.ge/images/favicon.ico' />
    <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="http://lingo.ge/css/default.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://lingo.ge/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://lingo.ge/js/menu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var domain='http://lingo.ge/';
        var link= [];
        function ERROR(){
            alert('error');
        }
        function dictionary(name){
            $('<div/>', { id: 'dictitle', text: name }).appendTo('#middle');
            $('<input/>', { id: 'searchword', type:'text', placeholder:'Search Words' }).appendTo('#middle');
            $('<div/>', { class: 'word' }).appendTo('#middle');
        }
        function run() {
            var page = link[0];
            var func = link[1];
            if(typeof(page) != "undefined" && page !== null){
                if(link.length === 2){
                    window[page](func);
                }else{
                    window[page]();
                }
            }else{
                ERROR();
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(link.length === 0){
                <?php
                    foreach($url as $key => $val){
                        echo 'link.push("'.$val.'");';
                    }
                ?>
            }
            run();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="http://lingo.ge/images/logo.png" width="250" height="75">
            <div id="headbanner"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftside">
            <ul>
                <li class='active'><div><span id="menu1">Home</span></div></li>
                <li><div><span>Products</span></div></li>
                <li class='last'><div><span>Contact</span></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="rightside"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doing nothing.
I tryed many kind codes but nothing happenned.
please help me.!

P.S. you can look the result on this link
http://lingo.ge/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In console it's showing Errors

1. DOC type declaration is wrong.
   Replace

> < !doctype html>

With

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

2 .  is $ is not defined.

To solve this jue jQuery noConflict() Method.

3 . by checking source I got that You have given relative path to your JS files. So it's not getting proper file.
Give absolute path as you have given in your Style Sheets.

Comment: as I know we are using $ symbol instead of Jquery.
so how can I declare it?

Comment: As I know you don't need to use that because root of all causes is DOC TYPE declaration. Fixing this will work your script.

Comment: no. nothing happenned. I tryed this tweaks. you can look the shared server on link: http://lingo.ge/

Comment: And have you checked for jQuery in your folder and it's relative file to your path ?

Comment: You have given relative path to your files, that's why it's not working. http://lingo.ge/js/menu.js this is working but due to relative path it's taking (http://lingo.ge/dictionary/js/jquery.min.js) this path, which doesn't exist. So give absolute path as you have given in your stylesheet.

Comment: I add the absolute path but nothing happenned too.

Comment: I add new path: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> but also nothing happenned please help

Answer (score 0):

I visited the link you provided, and it looks like you forgot to load jquery.

There's referenceError for $ being undefined. if you use the ready API on your html, you should declare jquery resource first ahead of the other script resources, which you did correctly but, probably not for the resource path.

==================================================================================

Above is my previous answer.
I updated this answer according to your update on your actual web app status.

==================================================================================

Now your jquery is loaded, but the console still throws undefined error for $.

I found out that you declared `$.noConflict()` at the entrance point of your script.

This means that $ is no longer represents jQuery object, giving all the control to the jQuery from $ object.

I see no point in using that API on your web. just get rid of the code or please replace all the $ to jQuery. then the undefined error will be solved.

If you still need that API to prevent possible script conflictions, then just specify a specific object name and use it throughout your script codes.

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function() {

     //now jq has all the control that $ object used to have.
     //code here..

}
```

Comment: no I have written <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script> also I had tryed library from ajax server but nothing happenned too. and I have $(document).ready(function(){ in the end of JS script

Comment: So what can I do? please help me. this code is working on jsfiddler and also working on 000webhost`s server + my own localhost but here on the real server not working.

Comment: write like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://lingo.ge/dictionary/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: I add new path: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script> but also nothing happenned

please help

Comment: OK. thank you ALL. I have done. but problem was not jquery  library. problem was in menu.js where I called the ID whitch was not declared. now everithing working very well. thank you ALL!